# Swift Realm Simulator Permission Denied

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I have been using RealmSwift for a while with no issues. However I have just started to get the following error when running Simulator with a Realm Swift Project

xcode: 8.2.1 (I am on El Capitain so this is the latest I can go)

RealmSwift: 3.0.2

Swift: 3.0.2.

> Error: Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=13 "Permission denied"
>
> file:///Users/michaelmoulsdale/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B83BA287-5365-4048-A813-042D63A194A6/data/Containers/Data/Application/78F3500D-975E-4A60-A674-203325588F3F/Documents/default.realm
>   fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=io.realm.unknown Code=13 "Permission denied"
>   UserInfo={Category=system, Error Code=13,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Permission denied}: file
>   /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.63/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift,
>   line 178

I have tried the following things
update Cocoa Pods for RealmSwift
I am in the progressing of re-installing Xcode from the developer downloads.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I finally deleted the CoreSimulator directory (file:///Users/michaelmoulsdale/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices)

When I ran the next simulation, this directory was recreated and all was well.

Odd little behaviour, no idea what caused it.